# How to loop over a sting that defines a Range?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This may be fairly simple, but i am not able to figure it out.

I am working on a peice of code where i need to loop over a range defined by the string.

Example:

```
service_range = 'AX000-AX930'

ouput :

'AX000'
'AX001'
'AX002'
'AX003'
'AX004'
.
.
.
'AX929'
'AX930'
```

I am trying to generate using the code below:

```
service_range = re.findall(r'\d+', service_range)
print(service_range)    # ['000', '930']

for i in range(int(service_range[0]), int(service_range[1] + 1)):
    print(i)  
    count += 1
```

above code works however the output is not quite what iwant. I want to preserve the digits & code ('AX')

```
0
1
2
3
.
.
.
.
930
```

Comment: you have to convert `001`, `930` to integer but next you have to generate again strings with `AX` - `f"AX{i:03}"`

Comment: `print(f"AX{i:03d}")` for newer version of python or `print("AX{0:0=03d}".format(i))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may concatenate the prefix, and padd-left the value, with a nicer regex that gives

```
import re

service_range = 'AX000-AX930'
prefix1, start, prefix2, end = re.search(r'([A-Z]+)(\d+)-([A-Z]+)(\d+)',
                                         service_range).groups()

assert prefix1 == prefix2
for i in range(int(start), int(end) + 1):
    print(f"{prefix1}{i:03d}")
```